# How to update and recall a javascript function after select different value from select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi i have this javascript at bottom of my page.

```
    var e = document.getElementById("path_chooser");
    var path= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    function update()
    {
    imgObj = document.getElementById('img1');
    if (!isChrome) imgObj.src = img.src;
    img.src = "cams/camera1.php?canal="+path+"&t="+(unique_name++);
    if (originalWidth == 0)
    {........ bla bla bla
```

i have a select dropdown

```
                <select id="path_chooser" >
                <option value="1">camera1</option>
                <option value="2" selected="selected">camera2</option>
                <option value="3">camera3</option>
                </select>
```

this javascript updates a camera image in a div, it works ok, now i need that the javascript updates the var "path" when user changes the selected camera.

i get the var path updated when i change the selection, but the div is not refreshed, please tell me how to do it.

Thanks a lot

Diego

Comment: Ehm, seems that the js you posted is not related to a) changing select b) updating divs. Please triple check that ;.)

Comment: Where is the `update` function called?

Comment: hi, i edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for handle onchange event for a drop down box:

```
<select id="path_chooser" onchange="getOption(this)">
            <option value="1">camera1</option>
            <option value="2" selected="selected">camera2</option>
            <option value="3">camera3</option>
            </select>

 function getOption(v)
 {
   var path= v.options[v.selectedIndex].value;
   imgObj = document.getElementById('img1');
   if (!isChrome) imgObj.src = img.src;
   img.src = "cams/camera1.php?canal="+path+"&t="+(unique_name++);
   .............................
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but i need the función uses the new value and the div shows the new image (based in new selected value)

Comment: Can you tell me how to get a default value for "path" ? the function shows an image and i dont want to wait until user choose some option in the select box.